# How to apply Polyglot Detector function to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, polyglot

Assuming I have a column called `df.Text` which contains text (more that 1 sentence) and I want to use polyglot `Detector` to detect the language and store the value in a new column `df['Text-Lang']` how do I ensure I also capture the other details like `code` and `confidence`

```
testEng ="This is English"
lang = Detector(testEng)
print(lang.language)
```

returns

> name: English     code: en       confidence:  94.0 read bytes:  1920

but

```
df['Text-Lang','Text-LangConfidence']= df.Text.apply(Detector)
```

ends with

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode' and Detector
>   is not able to detect the language reliably.

Am I applying the Detector function incorrectly or storing the output incorrectly or something else?

Comment: change datatype of your column to str and try again

Comment: That didn't resolve it, My datatypes are object already. This code ```from polyglot.detect import Detector
testEng ="This is English"
lang = Detector(testEng)
print(lang)``` will produce this output Prediction is reliable: True
 Language 1: name: English     code: en       confidence:   94.0 read bytes:  1920
 Language 2: name: un          code: un       confidence:     0.0 read bytes:     0
 Language 3: name: un          code: un       confidence:    0.0 read bytes:     0

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate that type of output into my dataframe?

Comment: it looks like a dictionary, can work, do place it in edited question for proper look though and also what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: can you include a sample of the contents of df.Text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, if you only need `polyglot` for language detection, you'd better use `pycld2` directly, that is what used behind the scenes. It has **much** cleaner API.

Saying that, the error you state comes from one of the values in your `Text` column, which is a real number. So you will have to convert values like that into strings.

The next problem you will stumble upon is minimal text length. `polyglot` will throw exception if the text is too short. You have to silence the exception by passing `quiet=True`.

Now, applying `Detector` will return an object. So you will have to parse it to extract the information you want. To extract language names, you will have to import `icu` module (it is a dependency of `polyglot`, so you have it installed already):

```
import icu
df.Text = df.Text.astype(str)
df['poly_obj'] = df.Text.apply(lambda x: Detector(x, quiet=True))
df['Text-lang'] = df['poly_obj'].apply(lambda x: icu.Locale.getDisplayName(x.language.locale))
df['Text-LangConfidence'] = df['poly_obj'].apply( lambda x: x.language.confidence)
```

After that you can drop the `poly_obj` column.

Comment: How do I deal with this error: input contains invalid UTF-8 around byte 191 (of 248).  I presume this is because I have chinese / japanses characters?  I thought Polyglot would need that to determine the language.

Comment: @B.Z.B :   Did you ever get an answer to that question? I have the same issue and can't get around it.

Comment: The problem is that some of the characters are not valid symbols (probably control characters). You need to sanitize them. Replace second line to `df.Text = df.Text.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join([ch for ch in x if ch.isprintable()]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
testEng ="This is English"
lang = Detector(testEng)
df['Text-Lang']=lang.language.code
df['Text-LangConfidence']=leng.language.confidence
```